# "Leider ist ein Serverfehler aufgetreten. Warten Sie eine Weile und versuchen Sie es später erneut." (English: server error, try again later)

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting this error when I try to run my Google App Script which is deployed as a web app. It worked fine yesterday with the same code.

What could that be? Does wait help?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could that be?

The GAS Team frequently changes the code, for instance, the `DatePicker` widget had no the `setName` method, only `setId` and this ID was used as a handler parameter. Recently they introduced the `setName` method and code became broken. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1658) is a submitted issue about this change. I assume you have similar situation.

> Does wait help?

No. I am not sure, that the code will start to work again... but who knows... I suggest you to start you script under the debugger, to find the problem line or lines and to try to fix it or write a workaround.